# Changing the behavior of the iOS Lockscreen

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7

Is there a way to change the behavior of the iOS Lockscreen? For instance, can an app, if active, provide a user with dynamic content, such as pictures, as the phone's background, and, in addition, allow a user to swipe left (in addition to swiping right, if they want to unlock the phone) to engage said content?

Comment: With or without jailbreaking the phone?  I don't think this is possible on non-jailbroken phones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the behavior of the iOS Lockscreen?

**No.**

> For instance, can an app, if active...

**No.**

iOS doesn't provide any API that would allow the sort of thing that you describe. It might be possible to modify or replace the lock screen if you jailbreak your phone -- all bets are off at that point. But an app that uses the Apple-provided API has no way to modify the lock screen.

Also, note that if the device is locked, [your app won't be active](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1). You may have intended a looser definition of "active," but looking at the linked chart of app states will help you understand that what you're looking to do isn't achievable with the current API. Apps have to be *active* to receive events, but a locked phone implies that your app will be in an *inactive*, *background*, or *suspended* state if it's running at all.

Answer (score 0):

No. (Not if you're talking about an 'app' in the sense of the App Store)

The only way an app can interact with the lock screen is through notifications, and cannot alter the standard lock screen interface.

You can alter the lock screen with a MobileSubstrate tweak on a jailbroken phone, but this requires reverse-engineering SpringBoard (the iOS launcher app), can be quite complicated and obviously cannot be distributed through the App Store